# Make Matrix NOT display as a table in the backend

Tags: matrix

is there a way to make Matrix not display as a table in the backend, but simply as a group of stacked fields?

Both WordPress and Drupal have "field collection" modules/plug-ins where each item is presented as a mini-form instead of in table format. Assuming Matrix is the only way to achieve a similar field collection in EE, I'd prefer the mini-form format. Otherwise, when a Matrix field collection has a lot of fields, you end up with a very wide table.

Any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: no. Matrix (and Grid) are designed to have a fixed number of columns and have content added one row at a time.

The simplest solution would be to add several custom fields and just display them in order on the publish screen.

But if that's out for whatever reason, then [Content Elements](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/content-elements) may do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks. Adding custom fields in order does not solve the problem in that the user should be able to add an unlimited amount of field groups (Matrix rows) if they need to. As far as Content Elements, that doesn't sound related.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want unlimited rows of a pre-defined "group" of rows?

Comment: Exactly. Unlimited rows, except not in row/column format, but in "mini-form" format. Client presses + and gets a new "mini-form" of stacked fields instead of a new row.